# NameError: name is not defined Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on a web crawler using scrapy 1.5 and am getting an error that row_list is not defined when it is. I believe this is a global issue but am not sure what would be the proper way to correct this. The reason I am keeping the code like this is because I need sublists with all the details in a row. So I can use the first element in the list as a key and join everything else after the first element into 1 element stored in the second position. I have to yield a dictionary and need it in this format. any help would be great.

```
def forklift_detail_parse(self, response):
    final_dict = {}
    # get the table with html tr and td
    table_list = response.css('div.block-wrapp.full-title.product-info > span > div > table > tr').extract()

    for rows in table_list:
        row_list = Selector(text=rows).css(
            'td::text, td > span::text, #pc-price > span:nth-child(1)::text, tr > td > div::text').extract()
        if len(row_list) <= 1:
            del row_list
        if len(row_list[1:]) > 1:
            row_list[1] = ''.join(row_list[1:])
            del row_list[2:]

        final_dict.update(row_list)




line 5 NameError: name 'row_list' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that you're calling `del row_list` and, after that, you try to update `final_dict` with that name.

Check out this example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x
1
>>> del x
>>> x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6fcf9dfbd479> in <module>
----> 1 x

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

When you call `del row_list`, the `row_list` name is gonna be removed from the namespace, thus you can't access it.

More about the `del` statement: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del

Comment: Thank you! I just realized what I was doing. I meant to delete a sub list within row_list not the whole list.